# How to search through text file content, if it was uploaded in Files tab?

Tags: lightning-experience, files, contentdocument

I uploaded a docx file in Files tab in lightning experience. Now I have to use it in Apex trigger, to check if Contact's Name is mentioned in this file. I know that in Salesforce classis you could use the body of Document for that purpose, something like this:

```
Document d = [select body from Document where name = 'TextFile];
for(String line : d.body.toString().split('\\n')) {
    //check here if document contains this Name
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar with a File in Lightning Experience?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The document itself (ContentDocument or ContenVersion) and the fact that you are using classic or lightning should not stop you from doing anything different. Your trigger is pretty much agnostic when it comes to environments for your specific use case.

However, 
Instead of converting your body into a string and then splitting each line of your document and checking if there is a name within it, you might want to leverage [SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm) and query the content of the body for the string/name.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as far as I know there is no body in ContentDocument. How should I search through it? Maybe you can provide some example for this

Comment: it is stored inthe content version associated to the document.